# Mongo query - Return only inner child Key Value

Tags: mongodb

I want to return only the value for DOC.AMOUNT greater than 9 Million. The problem is I am getting the parent DOC, where as I just want the child AMOUNT: 9000000. In other words, instead of `{Key: {Key:Value}}` I want `{Key:Value}}`.

My query:

```
db.acris.find({"DOC. AMOUNT" : {$gt : 9000000}},{"DOC. AMOUNT":1,_id:0}).pretty().limit(5)
```

Here is the result of my query:

```
{ "DOC" : { " AMOUNT" : 9000100 } }
{ "DOC" : { " AMOUNT" : 9001000 } }
{ "DOC" : { " AMOUNT" : 9002135.18 } }
{ "DOC" : { " AMOUNT" : 9002292 } }
{ "DOC" : { " AMOUNT" : 9003572 } }
```

How can I change the query so that I only get `{" AMOUNT" : value }` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework's **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** operator to reshape your documents. This will be piped after the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline which has the query logic and the **[`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit)** step which will pass the first 5 documents to be projected:

```
db.acris.aggregate([
    // acts as your query filter, similar to find()
    { "$match": { "DOC. AMOUNT": { "$gt": 9000000 } } }, 

    // similar to limit(5)
    { "$limit": 5 }, 

    // reshape your documents here
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "AMOUNT": "$DOC. AMOUNT"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: When you say it "reshape your documents" is that only for query results (i.e. temporary), or does it permanently reshape the documents in the collection?

Comment: Aggregations operations process data records and return computed results, they do not permanently change the document state in the collections, just like what you do with the `find()` method. Did you mean to permanently transform the documents in the collection or you want to transform the result from the query?

Comment: transform the result from the query

Comment: @user3062459 No worries, happy to help :)